# Using Webpack with Karma causes node modules loading error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, webpack, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am trying to just run my Jasmine Test with Karma and I believe some of the modules that should be loaded are not loaded, it could be a dependency issue but I am running out of ideas.

**karma.conf.js**

```
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');
webpackConfig.entry = {};

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',
    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        { pattern: 'test-context.js'}
    ],
    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],
    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
        'test-context.js': ['webpack']
    },
    webpack: webpackConfig,
    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true
    },
    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],
    // web server port
    port: 9876,
    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,
    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,
    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,
    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity,
    debug: true
  })
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './index.js'
  ],
  output: {
      publicPath: '/',
      filename: 'main.js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: 'json-loader'
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  node: {
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    //dns: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty'
  },
  externals: {
    //'crypto': 'crypto'
  },
  debug: true
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Web-Application",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A web application",
  "engines": {
    "node": "5.9.1"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "tests": "karma start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.23.0",
    "box-node-sdk": "^1.3.0",
    "ejs": "2.4.1",
    "express": "4.13.3",
    "node-libs-browser": "^2.0.0",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "heroku",
    "express"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^v6.4.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "express": "4.13.3",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.5.0",
    "karma-babel-preprocessor": "^6.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs2-launcher": "^0.5.0",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.2",
    "webpack": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.10.1"
  }
}
```

I added

```
node: {
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    //dns: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty'
  },
```

Into the code to remove a previous dependency problem, but that could have just fixed the service layer and maybe there are deeper dependency issues.

**Stack Trace:**

[image]

[image]

**Git Source**

https://github.com/noobiehacker/revaBoxWeb

Any help or hints is appreciated ><

Answer (score 0):

This example is a Node.js app that uses [express](https://github.com/expressjs/express), which requires Node.js built-in modules like `fs` or `net`. But you try to build a web app with webpack (the default target is `web`) and in the browser those modules are not available. Webpack told you that the modules couldn't be resolved, but you decided to empty them out, which leaves you with a run-time error.

In order to use `express` with webpack you need to configure [`target`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/) to `node`, so webpack won't touch built-in modules.

```
target: 'node'
```

You also need to remove the `node` config you added before.

> I am trying to just run my Jasmine Test with Karma

As mentioned above, you're building a Node.js app, but [Karma](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma) is a browser testing tool. It won't be able to run your code. Your code is meant to be run by node and also tested by node, not the browser.

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for your feedback and I have tried your solution but I am getting this error now : "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined", perhaps I should either find a way to load the libraries into the browser or not even use karma at all??

Comment: You can't load those into the browser, and webpack leaves calls `require('fs')` and other built-in modules untouched so they can be used by Node directly, `require` does not exist in the browser, even if it did you wouldn't have access to the file system in the browser. You can't use Karma to test an express app, and you don't need it for anything in that case, Jasmine is enough which doesn't rely on the browser.

Comment: So do you suggest to not use chrome and use phantonjs as the browser option?

Comment: No, I'm telling you that you are not building a browser app. You won't ever run it in a browser nor will you need any tools related to a browser. Webpack can also bundle backend apps, and the you simply run the bundle from node: `node bundle.js`.

Comment: ohh I am trying to build an angular app, maybe thats where the problem lies and I shouldn't be using express